# Subsequent WALs only work if I include a base backup

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup, write-ahead-logging

I'm trying to replicate a primary PostgreSQL database to a replica through the use of base backups and WALs. The basic idea is something like:

```
Day 1: base backup + WALs
Day 2: new WALs
Day 3: new WALs
...
Day n: new WALs
```

I was able to get some initial implementation going but only if I create a base backup every time. Here is the docker compose file:

```yml
services:
    primary-db:
        image: postgres:9.6.16
        container_name: primary-db
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
        volumes:
            - ./primary:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    replica-db:
        image: postgres:9.6.16
        container_name: replica-db
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
        volumes:
            - ./replica:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        container_name: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

And this is the script that simulates the backup and restore process:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PRIMARY="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )/primary"
REPLICA="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )/replica"
BASEBACKUP="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )/basebackup"
TIMEOUT=15
SLEEP=5
MAX_WAL_SENDERS=32
WAL_KEEP_SEGMENTS=100

# Names
first_names=("Alice" "Bob" "Charlie" "David" "Eve" "Frank" "Grace" "Hank" "Ivy" "Jack" "Kate" "Leo" "Mia" "Nathan" "Olivia" "Cladbury" "Gates" "Bobson")
last_names=("Adebayo" "Ariho" "Kamau" "Nkrumah" "Twinoburyo" "Mugisa" "Byamugisha" "Osei" "Zuma" "Sankara" "Obi" "Dlamini" "Asante" "Mugisha" "Ndiaye" "Oxmaul")

# Get the length of the array
num_first_names=${#first_names[@]}
num_last_names=${#last_names[@]}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Functions
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function await {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Waiting for $SLEEP seconds..."
  sleep $SLEEP
}

function await_wal {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Waiting for $(($TIMEOUT * 2)) seconds..."
  sleep $(($TIMEOUT * 2))
}

function check_directories {
  if [ ! -d "$PRIMARY" ]; then
    echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [ERROR  ]: $PRIMARY does not exist - please run 'docker compose up -d' first"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ ! -d "$REPLICA" ]; then
    echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [ERROR  ]: $REPLICA does not exist - please run 'docker compose up -d' first"
    exit 1
  fi
}

function create_wal_directories {
  if sudo mkdir $PRIMARY/wal > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Created the $PRIMARY/wal directory"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Cannot create $PRIMARY/wal directory"
  fi

  if sudo mkdir $REPLICA/wal > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Created the $REPLICA/wal directory"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Cannot create $REPLICA/wal directory"
  fi
}

function configure_host_based_authentication {
  sudo sed -i "s/#local   replication     postgres                                trust/local   replication     postgres                                trust/g" $PRIMARY/pg_hba.conf
  sudo sed -i "s/#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1\/32            trust/host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1\/32            trust/g" $PRIMARY/pg_hba.conf
  sudo sed -i "s/#host    replication     postgres        ::1\/128                 trust/host    replication     postgres        ::1\/128                 trust/g" $PRIMARY/pg_hba.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Configured the replication connection"
}

function configure_primary_database {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring wal_level"
  sudo sed -i "s/#wal_level.*/wal_level = replica/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring fsync"
  sudo sed -i "s/#fsync.*/fsync = on/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring synchronous_commit"
  sudo sed -i "s/#synchronous_commit.*/synchronous_commit = local/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring wal_sync_method"
  sudo sed -i "s/#wal_sync_method.*/wal_sync_method = fsync/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring archive_mode"
  sudo sed -i "s/#archive_mode.*/archive_mode = on/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring archive_command"
  sudo sed -i "s/#archive_command.*/archive_command = 'test ! -f \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal\/%f \&\& cp %p \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal\/%f'/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring archive_timeout"
  sudo sed -i "s/#archive_timeout.*/archive_timeout = $TIMEOUT/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring max_wal_senders"
  sudo sed -i "s/#max_wal_senders.*/max_wal_senders = $MAX_WAL_SENDERS/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring wal_keep_segments"
  sudo sed -i "s/#wal_keep_segments.*/wal_keep_segments = $WAL_KEEP_SEGMENTS/g" $PRIMARY/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Configured the WAL for the primary database"
}

function configure_replica_database {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring wal_level"
  sudo sed -i "s/#wal_level.*/wal_level = replica/g" $REPLICA/postgresql.conf
  # echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring archive_mode"
  # sudo sed -i "s/#archive_mode.*/archive_mode = on/g" $REPLICA/postgresql.conf
  # echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Configuring archive_command"
  # sudo sed -i "s/#archive_command.*/archive_command = 'test ! -f \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal\/%f \&\& cp %p \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal\/%f'/g" $REPLICA/postgresql.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Configured the WAL for the replica database"
}

function configure_replica_restoration {
  sudo cp recovery.conf $REPLICA/recovery.conf
  sudo sed -i "s/#restore_command.*/restore_command = 'cp \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal\/%f \"%p\"'/g" $REPLICA/recovery.conf
  sudo sed -i "s/#archive_cleanup_command.*/archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal \"%r\"'/g" $REPLICA/recovery.conf
  sudo sed -i "s/#recovery_end_command.*/recovery_end_command = 'pg_archivecleanup \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/data\/wal \"%r\"'/g" $REPLICA/recovery.conf
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Configured the restoration for the replica database"
}

function fix_file_permissions {
  sudo chown -R 100998:100998 $1
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Updated file permissions for $1"
}

function restart_database {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Restarting the $1 container..."
  if docker restart $1 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Restarted the $1 container"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Unable to restart the $1 container"
      exit 1
  fi
  await
}

function create_base_backup {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Creating the base backup..."
  if docker exec primary-db pg_basebackup -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/basebackup -Ft -z -P -Xf > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Created the base backup"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Unable to create the base backup"
  fi
}

function create_users_table {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Creating the users table..."
  if docker exec primary-db psql postgres -U postgres -c "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Created the users table"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [ERROR  ]: Unable to create the users table"
      exit 1
  fi
}

function add_users {
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Populating the users table..."
  for i in $(seq 1 $1);
    do
      # Generate a random index
      random_f_index=$((RANDOM % num_first_names))
      random_l_index=$((RANDOM % num_last_names))

      # Get the random name
      random_first_name=${first_names[random_f_index]}
      random_last_name=${last_names[random_l_index]}

      full_name="$random_first_name $random_last_name"

      if docker exec primary-db psql postgres -U postgres -c "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('$full_name');" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
        then
          echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Inserted record --> $full_name"
        else
          echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [ERROR  ]: Unable to insert record --> $full_name"
          exit 1
      fi
    done
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Populated the users table with $1 users"
}

function edit_user {
  if docker exec primary-db psql postgres -U postgres -c "UPDATE users SET name = '$2' WHERE id = $1;" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [INFO   ]: Updated user: [id = $1, name = $2]"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [ERROR  ]: Unable to update user: [id = $1]"
      exit 1
  fi
}

function checkpoint {
  if docker exec primary-db psql postgres -U postgres -c "CHECKPOINT;" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
    then
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Created a checkpoint"
    else
      echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [ERROR  ]: Unable to create a checkpoint"
  fi
}

function copy_base_backup {
  sudo cp -a $PRIMARY/basebackup/. $REPLICA/basebackup/
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Copied the base backup to the replica"
}

function copy_wal_files {
  sudo cp -a $REPLICA/pg_xlog/. $REPLICA/wal/
  sudo cp -a $PRIMARY/wal/. $REPLICA/wal/
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Copied the WAL files to the replica"
}

function extract_base_backup {
  sudo cp -a $REPLICA/basebackup/. $BASEBACKUP/
  sudo tar -xf $BASEBACKUP/base.tar.gz -C $BASEBACKUP/
  sudo rm $BASEBACKUP/base.tar.gz
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Extracted the base backup"
}

function clean_base_backup {
  sudo rm $BASEBACKUP/postgresql.conf
  sudo rm $BASEBACKUP/pg_hba.conf
  sudo rm -rf $BASEBACKUP/basebackup
  # sudo rm -rf $BASEBACKUP/wal
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Deleted files and folders we do not want to copy over"
}

function apply_base_backup {
  sudo cp -ar $BASEBACKUP/. $REPLICA/
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Applied the base backup (merged if needed)"
}

function remove_old_backups {
  sudo rm $PRIMARY/basebackup/base.tar.gz
  sudo rm $REPLICA/basebackup/base.tar.gz
  sudo rm -rf $BASEBACKUP
  sudo rm -rf $PRIMARY/wal/{*,.*}
  sudo rm -rf $REPLICA/wal/{*,.*}
  echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") [SUCCESS]: Deleted old base backup files"
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set up the databases
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Run the Docker containers
docker compose up --force-recreate -d

# Sleep to make sure all the files are available
await

# Check that the primary and replica directories exist
check_directories

# Create directory to store WAL files
create_wal_directories

# Configure replication connection
configure_host_based_authentication

# Configure the WAL for the primary database
configure_primary_database

# Configure the WAL for the replica database
configure_replica_database

# Fix the file permissions
fix_file_permissions $PRIMARY
fix_file_permissions $REPLICA

# Restart both database Docker containers
restart_database "primary-db"
restart_database "replica-db"

# Create a checkpoint
checkpoint

# Create a PostgreSQL base backup of the database
create_base_backup

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Populate the database
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Create the users table
create_users_table

# Add initial users
add_users 100

# Edit a user
edit_user 1 "INITIAL DATA"

# Create a checkpoint
checkpoint

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copy the base backup and WAL files to the replica
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Wait for the WAL files to be generated
await_wal

# Copy the base backup
copy_base_backup

# Copy the WAL files
copy_wal_files

# Extract the base backup
extract_base_backup

# Delete files and folders we do not want to copy over
clean_base_backup

# Apply the base backup (merge if needed)
apply_base_backup

# Configure the restoration for the replica database
configure_replica_restoration

# Change the owner of the replica database volume
fix_file_permissions $REPLICA

# Restart the replica database Docker container
restart_database "replica-db"

# Show the logs
docker logs replica-db

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Populate the database again
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

batches=(250 350)
for i in "${!batches[@]}";
  do
    remove_old_backups
    create_base_backup
    add_users ${batches[$i]}
    edit_user $i "BATCH: $i"
    await_wal
    checkpoint
    copy_base_backup
    copy_wal_files
    extract_base_backup
    clean_base_backup
    apply_base_backup
    configure_replica_restoration
    fix_file_permissions $REPLICA
    restart_database "replica-db"
    docker logs replica-db
  done
```

The basic flow of it is I add 100 records then perform the backup and restoration. I then do it again twice but with 250 and 350 records each time. This is working right now because when I log into the replica, I see a total of 700 records which adds up to what I expect it to have. But this approach always creates a base backup which I think is not necessary. On the last part of the script, if I comment out the parts about the base backup, the result ends up only having 100 records (the inital seeding of data and the restoration that included the base backup) - the restoration that DIDN'T include the base backup seems to have failed and I don't see the records restored on the replica database.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?